# PHP proxy to download files

Tags: php, proxy, download-manager, source-code-protection

I think this is a easy one.

I have a simple website with a reserved area and some files to download from it.

I disabled direct file download with .htaccess, and I manage the download of file via this simple proxy.php file:

```
// ....

if ($filename === null || !file_exists($proxiedDirectory.$filename)) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
}

if (!$site->is_logged_in()) { 
    http_response_code(403);
    exit;
}

$fp = fopen($proxiedDirectory.$filename, 'rb');

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

This code WORKS perfectly, but unfortunately I have a 1.2Gb file that users could download, and this script is too slow, and doesn't allow the full file download.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `header()`, `set_time_limit()`, `fgets()`, `ob_flush()`, `flush()`. Here is my example, best using Php 64bit on OS 64bit because `filesize()` has not limits in this architecture.

```
    // Set force download headers
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u", filesize($downloads_folder . $file)));
    // Open and output file contents
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fh = fopen($downloads_folder . $file, "rb");
    while (!feof($fh)) {
      echo fgets($fh);
      ob_flush();
      flush();
    }
    fclose($fh);
    exit;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use chunked download, smth like this:

```
$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;
while (!feof($fp))
{
    $buffer = fread($fp, $chunkSize);
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use nginx as proxy may be more suitable.
The reason is simple : 
when you download by php, there will be timeout when request in php-fpm, so the file more likely can not download complete.

```
location /proxy.lua {
    proxy_pass http://proxy.com/link/;
}
```

if you need to check user has login or not, you can use lua + nginx(OpenResty)

yet there is a simple way to check that:
1. proxy.php redirect the request to nginx location proxy.lua with two parameter: ts and code.

```
ts is timestamp of server
code is md5sum(ts+"complexstring")
```

```php
header("Location: /proxy.lua?ts=122&code=xxx&filename=xxxx", 302);
exit(0);
```

when in lua:

```lua
parse the parameter ts and code, validate the code and ts value
proxy the file
```

Comment: Thanks ryan, your answer is correct, but unfortunately I have a shared apache host :(

Comment: you can redirect the request to some host which is nginx or openresty.  When proxy a large file or the client network is not fast enough, timeout will be occurred definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_end_clean()` before `fpassthru($fp)`

e.g.

```
ob_end_clean();
fpassthru($fp);
```

This might work for large files